# How to transform a list of 2D-arrays (with one dimension varies) to a ragged tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, ragged, ragged-tensors

x is a list of 2D-arrays, and each 2D-array is a series of 6-tuple.

[image]

I want to transform x into a ragged tensor. I try
`xrag = tf.ragged.constant(x)` and

[image]

get `xrag` with `shape = (895, None, None)`, however its `shape` should be `(895, None, 6)`. Would it be OK or how to improve it?

Comment: Can you replace your screenshots with actual text data please? A [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some dummy data would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, thank you. I will post a new question with full description of my example procedure, and an easy MRE. Please see my new question later.

Comment: You can simply edit your current question.